# Photoelectric Effect combined with Doppler Redshift

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, photoelectric-effect, doppler-effect

Suppose we were standing in the vacuum with a photoelectric effect experiment. If we had a source of EM radiation emitting photons with a high enough frequency, we would begin to observe said effect and therefore register some current. Now let's say we are in the same scenario as before, but moving at a high enough speed away from the EM radiation source, which remains where it was before. Due to Doppler redshift, the photons colliding on our cathode would now be less energetic (their frequency would have diminished) and therefore we would cease to observe the photoelectric effect for high enough speeds.

Is this reasoning correct? If so, could we use these two effects combined to measure long distances / high velocities in space?

For instance, one could easily define a critical speed $v_0$ as the speed at which we cease to observe photoelectric effect because the Doppler effect has become so strong that even the most energetic photons emitted by the source do not have a frequency high enough to give place to the photoelectric effect. What is more, this speed would be directly related to the stopping potential, since both applying said potential and moving farther away from the source at a speed $v_0$ would cause the photoelectric current to drop to zero, and if we kept increasing either of these values, there would be no additional effects

Comment: I think everything you wrote is correct.